# SKAction runblock with arguments

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have been trying to implement the following functionality in my game. I run an action on the sprite node (sprite node parent is nil) and the action should wait for my specified time and then add the node to self. I could not find any action which adds the node to parent. I thought doing something like that:

```
node.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(timetowait), SKAction.runBlock(addToSelf(node))]))
```

and just having a method as this:

```
func addToSelf(node: SKSpriteNode){
    self.addChild(node)
}
```

If I succeed doing this, my game performance would improve a lot. Anyone knows is there a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. You should be able to use

```
SKAction.runBlock({ self.someFunction(param) })
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/runBlock:) for more details.

Comment: Hm, it does not give the error, but does not execute the code either

Comment: Edited my answer, try that.

Comment: Also, why not run self.addChild(node) directly within the block?